# C# Selenium - Send Keys Not Working - Downloading a File - Need Solution

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I am trying to automate the '`Downloading a File`' using `c# selenium` in the IE9 browser. I tried my level best in exploring the Google to find the solution but nothing helps or works out.

My approach is, i just used '`send keys`' but still the send keys are not able to send the keys.

Waiting for the solution. I am sure some one had automated this scenario.

---

```
Requirement specs:
Programming language:  C#
Automation Tool:Selenium
browser:IE9
```

Answer (score 0):

Some HTML and C# code will be nice. I can't understand why you use `SendKeys()` for

> automate the 'Downloading a File'

Usually if the page allows it, this method is used to *Upload* a file. You don't need Selenium to download a file, try with the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx):

```
using System.Net;
//...
WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
Client.DownloadFile("http://www.thereforesystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/image35.png", @"C:\mypicz\stackoverflowlogo.png");
```

Comment: Hi Ekostadinov, thank you so much for sharing your solution :D Your approach will work if the file is available in the server already BUT in my case, when i click a hyperlink - the system will create a PDF file in runtime. how to handle this situation  ????

Comment: Give us a bit of the code, so we could try and help you. How the file is available for a user to donwload? Is it a Windows popup, so you could save it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) .... The File is not available in the server. in the background. In the code behind we are creating PDF using PDFConverter like below:                                                                                                       var pdfConverter = new PdfDocumentCreator(); 
pdfConverter.WriteToHttpResponse(Response,FILENAME_PDF);                                                                                                                                                                             Yes its IE9 download popup at the bottom.

Comment: i want to save the file from 'Download popup' of IE9 browser.

Comment: Selenium can't handle those, you need something like [AutoIT](http://bharath-marrivada.blogspot.com/2011/02/selenium-autoitv3-file-upload-download.html).

Comment: oops.. do u have any example for AutoIT - Selenium - C#?

Comment: Here is a [video how-to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nezg9kk4neQ), the code is not C# but the flow is the same. Those articles will help you too:  [autoit example #1](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/), [autoit example #2](http://avinashpandeblogsonseleniumautomation.blogspot.com/2015/06/download-file-using-selenium-webdriver-c.html) and [autoit example #3](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/downloading-a-file-in-internet-explorer-through-selenium)